# Block specific div elements while importing from external source

Tags: javascript, block, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to grab a specific div container of an external source. But unfortunately there are also div IDs inside this div container, which aren't needed.

The grabbing works, but the blocking doesn't. FYI: I'm new to JavaScript and searched already for a solution.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="LinkToExternal.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#article').load('ExternalURL #DIV_Container');
       });

       document.getElementsByClassName('NotNeededClass').style.visibility = 'hidden';
       document.getElementById('NotNeededID').style.visibility = 'hidden';

    </script>        
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="article"></div>
        <div id="article2"></div>
    </div><!--container-->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have for hiding the elements is firing right after the load function.  The likely cause is that the elements you are trying to hide have not been loaded into the DOM.  Place your code in a callback function of the load function, this will ensure that your elements have been loaded into the DOM.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#article').load('ExternalURL #DIV_Container',function(){
           $('.NotNeededClass, #NotNeededID').hide();
       });
   });
</script>
```